# How to publish angular app using Azure DevOps Pipeline to AWS ECR/ECS

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Trying to Publish my Angular app using Azure DevOps pipeline to AWS ECR. I am new to Azure Pipelines and below is the code I have already managed to write. I have read the docs on Azure pipelines, but struggling to find the neccessary information. Could anyone please assist.

```
trigger:
- staging-release

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  AWS_REGION: eu-west-1                                       # set this to your preferred AWS region, e.g. us-west-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY: ********                      # set this to your Amazon ECR repository name
  ECS_SERVICE: ********                          # set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER: ********                                     # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ********      # set this to the path to your Amazon ECS task definition
                                                            # file, e.g. .aws/task-definition.json
  CONTAINER_NAME: ********                       # set this to the name of the container in the
                                                            # containerDefinitions section of your task definition


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    #Amazon Credentials
    - task: AWSCLI@1
      inputs: 
        awsCommand: 


    - script: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f Dockerfile.staging .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Steps or tasks I need to accomplish:

- Configure AWS credentials
- Login to AWS Amazon ECR
- Build tag and push docker image to ECR
- Fill in the new image ID in the AWS ECS task definition
- Deploy Amazon ECS task definition

Answer (score -1):

As you are using AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps, this document: [Supply task credentials using a service connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#service-connection) may help you to set up service connection with PAT to supply credentials to the task.

Comment: I managed to do build a docker image to AWS ECR, so it does work.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please refer to the instruction for AWS.